# How to get Name value using ID From another table (sql server)

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Table1 ID: 10001 Name: JM 
Table2 ID:       Name:
```

I make an relationship to relationship the ID to table1 and table2

table1 as primary and table2 as Foreign key

I'm using QR code scanner to insert data to table2 . when I scan the QR code with value of 10001 it will automatically saved the ID : 10001 to the table2 , then if i scan the ID not in the list it will give an error because of the relationship .

Here is my sql code:

```
  command.CommandText = " INSERT INTO Table2 (ID,Name) VALUES (@id,@name);";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", decoded_text);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", decoded_text);
```

Now, if i scan the 10001 ID . i want to automatically saved the Name "JM" also to the table2 .
Hope someone understand my point

Answer (score -1):

you should create a new field in database table that you want to add JM in it.
then you can use insert Query for insert data.
if possible please send your database tables structure in this post.
thanks.

Comment: My point is , if i scan the ID 10001 then name will also automatically saved to the table2